# sr_freecap: viewhelper calls eIDSR instead of eID - no image shown

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

i want to imeplement the extension [sr_freecap](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sr_freecap) in an own extension in a TYPO3 9 LTS. The viewhelper shows the text and the correct html but the link to the image looks like this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php?eIDSR=sr_freecap_EidDispatcher&id=9781&vendorName=SJBR&extensionName=SrFreecap&pluginName=ImageGenerator&controllerName=ImageGenerator&actionName=show&formatName=png&L=0&set=571e0
```

When i call this url manually i get the whole page and not the image. Is eIDSR correct? I was in the opinion that the correct call should be eID= ... I can't find information about it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This looks correct according to the source. But this question does not really match the QA model of Stack Overflow, so please ask your question in the TYPO3 Slack or in the [issue tracker of sr_freecap][1] instead.


  [1]: https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-sr_freecap

Comment: Thanks Matthias Brodola, very good hint - there is already a bug report about this problem. I will answer my question with a link to the bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the existing bug report: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89735

I tried the above solution and it works:

Put in your extension in which you implements sr_freecap this file:

```
/your-extension/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php
```

with the following content:

```
<?php
return [
    'frontend' => [
        'srfreecap-eidhandler' => [
            'target' => \SJBR\SrFreecap\Middleware\EidHandler::class,
            'before' => [
                'typo3/cms-frontend/content-length-headers',
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

this will work. Seems like a necaissary feature which is not mentioned in the manual.